# Change fontawesome icons using jquery on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, font-awesome

I have created a [`navigational menu`](http://jsfiddle.net/pjQP7/8/) with some of them having submenus. I want the menuitem with `fa-chevron-down`(down arrow icon) to change to change to `fa-chevron-up` (up arrow icon) when user clicks on that menu item and changes back when user clicks anywhere else. Plus i also have two request,

> 1) Since i am very new to jquery, the jquery code that i wrote seems to
>   do the trick but is there a better way? (notice when one menu item is clicked twice the sliding takes place twice. ITS ANNOYING)
>
> 2) When user resizes the window the html elements doesnot stays in place
>   and scatters.

Thanks in advance.

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pjQP7/8/)

**UPDATE :
Thanks for solving my problem. I refined my problem further and it is working perfectly. Here is the final**** [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pjQP7/11/)**

Comment: I changed the jsfiddle. I didn't update the code!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For changing the icon you can easily do something like this in your click event:

```
$(this).find($(".fa")).removeClass('fa-chevron-down').addClass('fa-chevron-up');
```

for More take a look at jsfiddle example:

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/pjQP7/10/)

Comment: Thank you very much. Your edited jsfiddle not only solved my fontawesome problem but also solved every other problem. Now my menu doesnot shows up twice when clicked 2nd time and rather it closes right up. THANKS A LOT. http://jsfiddle.net/pjQP7/9/

Comment: just one more question. If you notice closely, if you click on the icon itself it behaves differently and when you click on the menu name it behaves differently. WHY ?

Comment: I just Updated jsfiddle, take a look at it.

Comment: If you don't have any other classes, you can simply do a `$('.fa').attr('class','fa fa-chevron-up');`

Answer (score 12):

I think there is no need for changing the class.

If you only want to change the `fa-chevron-down` to `fa-chevron-up` icon, instead of switching the classes, just use `toggleClass` for `fa-rotate-180`. `fa-rotate-180` will rotate your icon and it might solve your purpose. No need for adding/removing individual classes.

Let's say:

```
$('selector').click(function(){
    $('menu-selector').toggleClass('fa-rotate-180');    
});
```

It's just a sample. You  can work around it.

Comment: how can i point to `i` tag when clicked on `a` tag in this code `<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>`.

Comment: You can refer to i using $(this).find('i:first') or $(this).children();

Comment: I loved your solution. http://jsfiddle.net/pjQP7/9/ I solved my other major problems using your solution.

Comment: Just one more question. If you notice closely, if you click on the icon itself it behaves differently and when you click on the menu name it behaves differently. Can you tell me why. Please

Answer (score 5):

Font Awesome v5 has changed things quite a bit.

This is the code I used to get a plus/minus collapse button working with Bootstrap, JQuery and FontAwesome.

HTML:

```
<a class="btn btn-collapse" id="btn-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-section"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></a>
```

JQuery script:

```
$("#btn-collapse").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('collapsed')) {
        $(this).find('svg').attr('data-icon', 'minus');
    } else {
        $(this).find('svg').attr('data-icon', 'plus');
    }
});
```

You should be able to substitute plus/minus for chevron up and down.